# Can't use column name "desc" in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, web

```
INSERT INTO movie (id, title, desc, released, views, featured) VALUES ('', 'title', '
\r\n    description
\r\n', '2006-12-12', '0', '0')
```

error is

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'desc, released, views, featured) VALUES ('', 'title', '
>   \r\n  description \r\n', ' at line 1

table structure is

```
id [ (pk, auto_inc) int(11) ]
title [ varchar(256) ]
desc [ text ]
released [ date ]
views [ int(11) ]
featured [ int(11) ]
```

running in phpmyadmin sql editor

Comment: You must use backticks `` around the desc word ` desc ` (skip the spaces in the start and the end though)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

desc is a [mysql reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). you must use backticks `` with the columns which are reserved words.

```
INSERT INTO movie (id, title, `desc`, released, views, featured)...
```

You should avoid using reserved words as column name or must use backticks (``)

Answer (score 4):

The word `desc` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and must be in backticks when used as a column name.

```
INSERT INTO movie (id, title, `desc`, released, views, featured) VALUES
-- ...etc...
```

I'd also advise you not to use `desc` as a column name in future as it is confusing and will just cause problems. You could use `description` instead, for example.

Answer (score 3):

DESC is a reserved word of MySQL and if you use it for naming consider using `desc`.