# Mysql Won't update the row

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Whats wrong with this query mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200174/whats-wrong-with-this-query-mysql)

I am using mysql and php to update a record. Here is my code:

```
$n=mysql_query("UPDATE chondas SET model='$model1', yearstart=$yearstart1,
                yearstop=$yearstop1, desc='$desc1', hp='$hp1', 
                engine='$engine1',trim='$trim1', weight='$weight1' WHERE id=$id1");
```

In the following code if I take out `desc='$desc1'` everything works perfectly. What would cause this error?

When i tested the following code in phpmyadmin I got this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc='text of the textarea' at line 1.

Comment: Hey Ers. Thanks for the quick reply. I am pretty sure the error is related to mysql rather than php. Because without "desc" everything is perfect. BTW desc's length is 10,000. I don't know if it might affect that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DESC` is a [reserved word in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) so you need to use backticks:

```
UPDATE chondas SET model='$model1', yearstart=$yearstart1, yearstop=$yearstop1, `desc`='$desc1', hp='$hp1', engine='$engine1',trim='$trim1', weight='$weight1' WHERE id=$id1
```

You should also switch to PDO (or mysqli) and prepared statements with bound variables to avoid potential sql injection.

Comment: I am amazed how fast and accurate the answers are on this website. Thank you!

Comment: @user1959665 I answered 3 minutes earlier, see the first comment posted immediately below your question. Click the link and read the answers on the page.

Comment: My comment above is a general comment to all of you! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`DESC` is a reserved word in MySQL.

Escape it with backticks

```
 `desc` = '$desc1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query won't run if you include the variable names in phpMyAdmin, such as:

```
UPDATE chondas SET model='$model1', yearstart=$yearstart1,
yearstop=$yearstop1, **desc='$desc1'**, hp='$hp1', 
engine='$engine1',trim='$trim1', weight='$weight1' WHERE id=$id1
```

Also, the PHP won't run if you mix your "" and '' e.g: `"UPDATE chondas SET model='$model1'...`