# You have an error in your SQL syntax error appearing with correct syntax

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am making an app in python flask, and I executed a sql query. I am using Mysql server 8.0.
My code is:

```
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="...",
        password=".....",
        database="....."
    )
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    sql = "INSERT INTO calender_events (class,date,title,desc) VALUES (%s, %s ,%s, %s)"
    val = (str(student_class), str(date.today()),title,desc)
    cursor.execute(sql, val)
    mydb.commit()
```

I get the error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc) VALUES ('8a', '2023-01-23' ,'er', 'er')' at line 1
```

although my syntax is correct, I think. I do not know my this error is occuring. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to check the contents of `val` before preparing the query? Are they as you expect? Did you try to check what the prepared query will look like? Does that look right?

Comment: @RiggsFolly no, they match up properly (and if that were the problem, it would be reported as a Python syntax error, not an SQL one).

Comment: might this be because `desc` is a reserved word in MySQL? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/why-can-t-we-use-column-name-desc-in-mysql#:~:text=The%20desc%20is%20a%20MySQL,let%20us%20create%20a%20table.

Comment: likely that's the issue I think, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200174/cant-use-column-name-desc-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `desc` is a reserved word in MySQL. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200174/cant-use-column-name-desc-in-mysql), which shows you should use

```py
sql = "INSERT INTO calender_events (class,date,title,`desc`) VALUES (%s, %s ,%s, %s)"
```

note the backticks around `desc`. Alternatively, you could use a different name for this column, maybe `description`?